# Flash NetStream.Buffer.Flush firing repeatedly

Tags: actionscript-3, buffer, flv, flush, netstream

I've made a custom video player in as3. Everything works, but once a video has loaded and played through completely, if the user replays the video it continuously fires the NetStream.Buffer.Flush event until the video stops playing again (by either ending or by the user hitting pause).
It doesn't seem to effect anything negatively, but I would rather not have an event continuously firing in the background like that.

I can't find any documentation of this happening online anywhere. Is this normal behavior for a NetStream that has fully loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've fixed it, though I'm still not sure why it was repeatedly firing the flush event.

My custom videostream class was set to seek(0) once the video completed to rewind the current flv. It seems this was what was causing the issue. Instead of using seek(0), I just reset the source back to the original url, which reloads the video completely. Since the video is cached at that point, it reloads immediately so it's not an issue.